# How to save a web page as MHT in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, mht

How do you save a web page as .mht in Chrome?

I have Chromium 18. It's supposed to be [possible](http://chromestory.com/2011/05/chrome-gets-mhtml-support-save-and-view-files-in-mht-format/) but I can't figure out how...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Viewing and creating MHTML files in current versions of Google Chrome is supported by toggling the "Save Page as MHTML" option on the `chrome://flags` page.

However, enabling this experimental option disables saving pages as HTML-only or HTML Complete files. From the `chrome://flags` page:

> **Save Page as MHTML** Mac, Windows, Linux
>   Disables saving pages as HTML-only or HTML Complete; enables saving pages only
>   as MHTML: a single text file containing HTML and all sub-resources.

Comment: You saved my life!! +1 I'm sorry I can't give you +1000... ;)

Comment: As of July 2013 there are still lots of short comings with this chrome flag. I'd recommend Vinay's answer if your web pages have complex content

Comment: I wonder how these options are ordered, and if we can change this order... Now I have "Webpage, Single file" (mhtml extension/format) as default, which is a nuisance because actually we most often use "Webpage, HTML only" option.

Comment: Works with [vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com)://flags too! Moreover, one can chose the file name and where to save it. I only miss the extra line with a link to the original URL at the bottom of the page. I have grown accustomed to this with the [UnMHT](http://www.unmht.org/unmht/en_index.html) Firefox extension.

Answer (score 4):

You can save it as MHTML file by using ["SAVE AS MHTML" extension available in chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/singlefile/mpiodijhokgodhhofbcjdecpffjipkle) which will capture the entire site to a compressed file.

Supported by Firefox, Internet Explorer and Chrome.

Comment: I can't find such an extension. Can you give us the link?

Comment: To add to [Vinay](http://superuser.com/users/156457/vinay)'s answer (Rep less than 50), and [slhck](http://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck)'s question, the extension is called [SingleFile](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/singlefile/mpiodijhokgodhhofbcjdecpffjipkle/related?hl=en) and it also requires [SingleFile Core](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/singlefile-core/jemlklgaibiijojffihnhieihhagocma/related) installed to work.<br>Navigate to options by R-clicking button on the right of the address bar. <br>The single file option in the drop-down save-as dialog generates the pa

Answer (score 4):

Starting June 2019, the **Save Page as MHTML** flag has been removed from Chrome. A [solution](https://techdows.com/2019/06/google-removes-save-page-as-mhtml-flag-from-chrome.html) that still works (for now?) is adding the `--save-page-as-mhtml` argument to Chrome's command line.

Comment: Damn, really? :( +1

Answer (score 0):

You can install free WizBrother SaveAs Plus plugin

http://wizbrother.com/saveasplus/index.html

By the way, it supports most of the web browsers, such as, IE, Firefox, Google Chrome, Safari, and Opera etc.

Comment: This is actually brilliant - nothing before have I found to work on saving complex gmail inbox web pages - this does it, which I find quite incredible! Before that, the best method I found, oddly, was Opera (pre-chromium!) for saving complex webpages with all objects and dependencies in tact. MIND YOU this plugin does take a while to save a page (at least the complex gmail inbox home page I tried) - AND it only worked by saving in IE, then opening in IE - but boy is it worth it if you have an important complex page to archive with FULL formatting in tact!

Answer (score 0):

There is now "Webpage, Single File" format that can be used.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Nope. That story is incorrect. While Chrome is capable of **viewing** mhtml files, it still doesn't save webpages to that format.

Yes it is a pain in the rear. But you can use AutoHotkey to read a list of links and save them to mhtml :)  AFAIK, this is easiest in IE, since no other browser makes it easy for AutoHotKey to check if the webpage has fully loaded.

Comment: Also FireFox has an extension for saviong in MHT: [UNMHT](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/unmht/) - in case someone is interested in.

Comment: This is false information. I save to MHTML using Chrome and have been a long time. It creates a single file no different then Firefox or IE.

Comment: @subjectivist: Sigh.  This post is **five years old**.

Comment: @surfasb: FYI, you can always update your answer.

Answer (score -1):

The "Save Page as MHTML" option (in Chrom://flags) does NOT allow you to view MHTML documents.  It only allows (requires) you to save web pages as MHTML.  (That is, if you enable it, you lose the ability to save a page as HTML with associated folder of related files.  You can ONLY save as MHTML.)  MHTML documents on a website are still downloaded, not viewed in Chrome.

Comment: I could open MHTML file in Chrome, that's false.