# headless chrome save page as mhtml

Tags: google-chrome, save-as

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to make Chrome save a site in MHTML from command line. I'm aware of `--print-to-pdf`, `--dump-dom`, and `--screenshot` but neither of them is what I'm after.

Anyone knows the answer to this?

Note: I know [how to turn on MHTML option in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/369232/).

Comment: As it states that the normal "Save as HTML" behavior is disabled I'd try to find an option on headless chrome that just saves the HTML?

Comment: It's not using headless Chrome, but take a look at this [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/55040/save-a-single-web-page-with-background-images-with-wget) which asks how to accomplish the same thing using wget:

Comment: wget is not enough, given how much site requires js to render images, thanks to lazy load.

Comment: Related question on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60352003/974555

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and not an elegant solution, but you could probably do this using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to simulate saving manually at the headless machine by passing appropriate keystrokes.

Comment: Are you sure OP is using a platform which AHGK will run? And that there is an interface to direct the keystrokes to?